# Animate Chart.JS Only Once

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've delayed animation of a Chart.js canvas until it's brought into the viewport, but am struggling to limit this to only one animation. I'd greatly appreciate any input on this.

Here's the code:

```
var inView = false;
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemBottom >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView('#trigger')) {
        if (inView) { return; }
        inView = true;
        new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).Line(data, {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRation: true,
            animationSteps: 175,
            showScale: false,
            scaleShowGridLines : false,
            scaleShowLabels: false,
            showTooltips: false
       });
    } else {
        inView = false;  
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't you need an `animation` attribute as well?  I would think that marking that as `false` if you have already scrolled into view should be the right way to go.  See [`chart.js` documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration)  What is it doing right now?

Comment: Animation is on by default in Chart.js's global settings (which you can use to have it on or off). The animation I'm describing works great, but it runs every time #trigger is scrolled into view. I would like the animation to occur only the first time this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of whether the chart was already generated. The trigger element is one place you can do this (if you are not using the same trigger for multiple charts), otherwise you could use the canvas element as well.

You also don't need `inView`

```
...
if (isScrolledIntoView('#trigger')) {
    if ($('#trigger').data("generated")) { return; }
    $('#trigger').data("generated", true);
    ...
```