# Delay animation of chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am new in this, my charts are starting automatically when page load, so my question is how to delay animation till it become in the view port, what is the code to do this and also where exactly to put it in chart.js?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/33356826/360067

Comment: Yes, i saw this but as i mentioned my JS skills in little so where exactly i will but this code (or under what) in chart.js to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to install:  chartjs-plugin-deferred [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-deferred)
And then add to your item

```
plugins: {
    deferred: {           // enabled by default
        xOffset: 150,     // defer until 150px of the canvas width are inside the viewport
        yOffset: '50%',   // defer until 50% of the canvas height are inside the viewport
        delay: 500        // delay of 500 ms after the canvas is considered inside the viewport
    }
}
```